# Creating Network Bridge in ArchLinux stops internet connectivity

Tags: networking, arch-linux, bridge, iproute2

I tried to add a new bridge interface in ArchLinux. I followed the [instructions from the wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Network_bridge) but after assigning the bridge to the real interface I cannot connect anymore to other IPs from outside (for example pinging an IP like 8.8.8.8).

What I did:

```
sudo ip link add name br0 type bridge

# should be up anyway but just to follow the wiki page:
sudo ip link set enp5s0 up

sudo ip link set enp5s0 master br0
```

After the last command I get "Destination Host Unreachable" from ping.

Here is the output of `ip addr`:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp8s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 2c:fd:a1:59:70:78 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: enp5s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq master br0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 2c:fd:a1:5a:91:45 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.178.42/24 brd 192.168.178.255 scope global noprefixroute enp5s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 2a0c:d242:3503:2400:8a5e:e525:faea:791e/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 6025sec preferred_lft 2425sec
    inet6 fe80::e5dd:e996:1b86:7dd/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: wlp4s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 4000
    link/ether dc:ef:ca:f0:b2:5f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
5: wlp3s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether e0:4f:43:70:90:f8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
6: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 66:6c:16:c8:ef:88 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
7: br-7fc0362fd380: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 02:42:d6:b1:8b:a2 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.18.0.1/16 brd 172.18.255.255 scope global br-7fc0362fd380
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
12: br0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 8a:a1:41:27:82:4d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

And this is the output of `ip route`:

```
default via 192.168.178.1 dev enp5s0 proto dhcp src 192.168.178.42 metric 203 
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown 
172.18.0.0/16 dev br-7fc0362fd380 proto kernel scope link src 172.18.0.1 linkdown 
192.168.178.0/24 dev enp5s0 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.178.42 metric 203
```

As you can see the real interface is `enp5s0` and there is also docker running which has its own bridge(s). I also have a WIFI interface but I'm not using it. For the tests I stopped the `dhcpcd` service. As it was running it also assigned `br0` an IP from my router and also added the correct route.

I also tried the approach with `bridge-utils` and `netctl` but I had the same issues there.

Any suggestions to get the bridge running without loosing the internet connection?

Comment: It might be helpful to tell use what you intend to accomplish with this bridge (i.e. is this for use with your docker containers, or some other scenario). When you bridge network links, they loose their layer-3 IP address. It is assumed that the bridge must be assigned the layer-3 IP address and mask if you want to access the network from the host.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bridge also has a link state, it needs to be set to UP.

```
sudo ip link set br0 up
```

The IPs and routes should be configured on the bridge, not on the ethernet interface. 
Both need to be up.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't help. Still the same.

Comment: Can you update the ip addr and ip route outputs? Any firewalling in place, are you using NetworkManager?

Comment: Somehow it's working now. I'm not sure if I solved it with something else or maybe it's not working with the next boot. Let's see.